# $\mathbb{R}^n/\sim$ homeomorphic to [0,1)

Tags: general-topology

Im having some trouble with the following:
Let n be a positive integer, and let $||\cdot||$ denote the usual Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is, $||x||=(x^2_1+…+x^2_n)^{1/2}$ where $x=(x_1,…,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a topological space equipped with the standard topology, and define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $x \sim y \iff ||x||=||y||$.
Show that $\mathbb{R}^n/\sim$ (equipped with the quotient topology) is homeomorphic to [0,1) (equipped with the standard topology).

I know that we say that X and Y (two topological spaces) are homeomorphic if there exist a homeomorphism, a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ which is bijective, continuous and $f^{-1}:Y \rightarrow X$ is continuous aswell.

I know I have to find a function/homeomorphism (a quotient map), but I am unsure of how to do so. 
I was thinking something like:
$v \mapsto f(||v||) \cdot v$
But I honestly dont know how to approach such a problem…

Comment: What about $f(x)=|x|/(|x|+1)$ ?  [by $|x|$ meaning what you use the double bar for, i.e. Euclidean norm on n-space.]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> First, can you describe the equivalence classes, perhaps geometrically? Then, can you see a nice way to describe the _set_ of equivalence classes?

Comment: Break it into two steps. First show that the equivalence classes are vectors of the same length and thus get mapped to the ray $[0,\infty)$, then show that the ray is homeomorphic to the half interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Lemma.** Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ a continuous surjection. Consider $\sim$ on $X$ given by: $x\sim y$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$. Then $f$ induces the following continuous bijection:
> $$F:X/\sim \to Y$$
> $$F([x]_\sim)=f(x)$$
> which is a homeomorphism if $f$ is a quotient map.

*Proof.* $F$ is of course well defined. It is easy to see that it is a bijection as well. Furthermore it is continuous because if $\pi:X\to X/\sim$ is the standard projection then $\pi^{-1}(F^{-1}(U))=f^{-1}(U)$ and thus $F^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Finally if $F^{-1}(U)$ is open, then by the above so is $f^{-1}(U)$ and thus if $f$ is a quotient map, then $U$ is open. Meaning $F$ is a quotient map as well. But a bijective quotient map is a homeomorphism. That's because for bijections $V=F^{-1}(F(V))$, and since $F$ is a quotient map, then this implies it is open. Or equivalently its inverse is continuous. $\Box$

---

With that consider

$$f:\mathbb{R}^n\to [0,\infty)$$
$$f(v)=\lVert v\rVert$$

This function is of course continuous.

Furthermore it is a quotient map. Indeed, assume that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open while $U\subseteq [0,\infty)$ is not. This means that there is $r\in U$ and a sequence $(x_n)\subseteq [0,\infty)\backslash U$ convergent to $r$. Now choose a vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\lVert v\rVert=r$. Of course $v\in f^{-1}(U)$. Next take $v_n=\frac{x_n}{r}v$ and note that $\lVert v_n\rVert = x_n$. Finally $v_n\to v$. However $v_n\not\in f^{-1}(U)$ which cannot happen since the last set is open. Note that the special case when $r=0$ has to be treated separately, which I leave as an exercise. Also note that the same works for any dimension (even infinite) and any norm.

Thus, by our lemma, $f$ induces a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n/\sim$ and $[0,\infty)$. As the final step pick your favourite homeomorphism $[0,\infty)\to [0,1)$, e.g. $\text{arctan}$ or something.

Comment: Thank you, I am a little unsure about the last step? Can I just choose arctan? again this is not that trivial to me…

Comment: @LilyHansen more precisely $x\mapsto\frac{2}{\pi}\text{arctan}(x)$ is a homeomorphism $[0,\infty)\to [0,1)$ with inverse $x\mapsto\text{tan}(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$. Another option is $x\mapsto \frac{x}{x+1}$ with inverse $x\mapsto \frac{x}{1-x}$.